# custom renderer to show title for each content page in a Xamarin tabbed page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a tabbed page which sits at the bottom of the screen and so has it's own custom renderer to achieve this.

I want to amend the renderer so that on UpdateSelectedTabIndex(Page page) the content pages get their own title, as this is overridden by the tabbed page it seems and no title is visible.

I was thinking along the lines of the code below but it doesn't work, can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
void UpdateSelectedTabIndex(Page page)
{
    var index = Element.Children.IndexOf(page);
    _bottomBar.SelectTabAtPosition(index, true);
    if(index == 0)
    {
        page.Title = "HOME";
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not the same at the duplicate @GeraldVersluis because, the renderer code is plateform specific

Comment: the accepted answer in the linked question won't work in my situation as the tabbed page will still override the content page title